# How to build specific dist folder by specific branch in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

How to build specific dist folder by specific branch in GitLab CI/CD ?
I got a main project that includes two folders，I want to build the project if I change the specific folder，such as when I changed code in Web1 folder ，then the CI/CD will be triggered and only build Web1 folder，not build all folders in the same time?

```
stages:
   - build

 build:
   stage: build
   tags:
     - test
   only:
     - test
   script:
     # - Web1
       - cd Web1
       - npm install
       - npm run build
       - rm - rf /home/user/test/web1
       - cp - r../dist/web1 /home/user/test/web1
       - cd..

     # - Web2
       - cd Web2
       - npm install
       - npm run build
       - rm - rf /home/user/test/web2
       - cp - r../dist/web2 /home/user/test/web2
       - cd..
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create two different jobs for this, which are triggered differently with the help of the keyword [changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges).

One job should be triggered when changes are made in the "Web1" folder

```
build_web1:
 stage: build
 only:
  changes:
   - Web1/**/*
 script:
  - ...
```

and the other when changes are made in the "Web2" folder

```
build_web2:
 stage: build
 only:
  changes:
   - Web2/**/*
 script:
  - ...
```